# Which approach to use for validating presence of a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

Given

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

If I want to validate that a comment always has a post, should I use

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  validates :post, presence: true
end
```

or

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  validates :post_id, presence: true
end
```

?

The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) suggests the `validates :post, presence: true` approach, saying:

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to
>   test whether the associated object itself is present, and not the
>   foreign key used to map the association.

One difference I can see between the two is that if you do

```
post = Post.new
comment = Comment.new
comment.post = post
comment.save
```

then validation fails if it's based on `post_id`, but succeeds if it's based on `post`. The latter makes more sense to me.

However, I sometimes see people in real life using the `post_id` approach. Are they simply using the "wrong" approach, or is there a rationale I'm not aware of?

The [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) doesn't have anything related to this topic.

The question [Rails ActiveRecord:: Proper way for validating presence on associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226116/rails-activerecord-proper-way-for-validating-presence-on-associations) seems to be asking about how to get a project to work using the `post_id` approach, but doesn't seem to explain why it's using that approach.

[Rails 4: Difference between validates presence on id or association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012252/rails-4-difference-between-validates-presence-on-id-or-association) is about validation, but merely describes the different effects of the two approaches, rather than saying why `post_id` should be used.

The question [Rails - Validate Presence Of Association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689888/rails-validate-presence-of-association) is unrelated - it's talking about validating that a post has at least one comment, which is a different requirement to what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a single case would fit all scenarios.

In the case of `post`s and `comment`s, I would tend to validate on the `foreign_key` rather than the association. This is partly due to better performance but also testing the `Comment` model would become independent of the `Post` model.

For the example of `Comment` and `Post`, when creating a comment, I would set association (i.e. `comment.post = post` or `post.comments.create!`) rather than the foreign_key (i.e. `comment.post_id = post.id`), so I know that the post exists (and that's why I am not validating the presence of the association). However in the unlikely case of data corruption, this will not have a significant impact on the application (just one comment wouldn't be associated with an existing post).

In other scenarios, where you need to be absolutely sure that the association is present, you could be extremely safe and validate the association (for instance a `CreditCard` belongs to a `User` or an `Invoice` belonging to an `Account`).

Answer (score 0):

The comments section of the blog post http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/ , linked to from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25808182/38765 suggests that some people validate on the `post_id` just because they weren't aware of other ways of doing it:

> Thanks for posting this! I've always validated on the field. I didn't
>   even think about validating the association.

and

> Amazing, thank you. That was subtle.

One person said `post_id` may have better performance:

> Keep in mind that validating on `:account` instead of `:account_id`
>   will incur a performance penalty, as the database has to be queried to
>   check that the association exists.

but I tend to be wary of doing things for performance reasons.